# Combine Data Frame with a List of Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

Say I have a data frame x and a list of 2 data frames L that contains that data frames y and z.

What is the best way to create a third list M that contains the dfs x, y and z?

I tried this but every column of x became an element of M.

```
M = c(x,L)
```

I'm sure there's some simple solution I am missing here.

Comment: `L[[3]] <- x`? `L <- append(L,x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
M <- c(L,list(x=x))
```